# Is there a way to use PowerShell ISE Add-ons on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, powershell-ise

I've created some Add-ons on PowerShell ISE to connect to some services like: Office 365, Exchange Online, Sharepoint Online, PowerCLI, Dell Storage, etc.

I am now trying to migrate from PowerShell ISE to Visual Studio Code and I can't find a way to use Add-ons there. Any tips?

Comment: Are these ISE add-ons, or are they Powershell modules?

Comment: Add-ons... The ones you add on the ISE profile and execute using shortcut keys or going in the add-ons menu.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution! (Sorry, I'll correct my mistake and post the solution here and not only the link...)

Just use "Register-EditorCommand" cmdlet.

On your profile script file, add something like this:

```
Function Connect_PowerCLI {
    $VMwareCredential = Get-Credential
    $ESXiHosts = @("esxi01","esxi02","esxi03")
    $ESXiHosts | ForEach-Object {
        Connect-VIServer -Server $_ -Credential $VMwareCredential
    }
}
Register-EditorCommand -Name Connect_PowerCLI -DisplayName "Connect on all ESXi hosts using VMware PowerCLI" -Function Connect_PowerCLI
```

Configure your VSCode shortcut:

```
{
  "key": "shift+alt+s",
  "command": "PowerShell.ShowAdditionalCommands",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'powershell'"
}
```

Then, with Visual Studio Code opened, press SHIFT+ALT+S and select what you need to be executed.

Jeffery Hicks original post:
https://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/powershell/5907/extending-vscode-with-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code has a completely different extensions model from the Powershell ISE and I would not expect the two to be compatible. You're best off finding VSCode extensions that fill in the functionality you're looking for.